# rails activerecord limit after order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to build a query using ActiveRecord, and I'm finding that executing a limit() and/or where() after order() is not working.

Here's my code:

```
candidates = Candidate.order("created_at desc")
puts candidates.to_sql
#prints SELECT "candidates".* FROM "candidates"   ORDER BY created_at desc
candidates.limit(20)
puts candidates.to_sql
#prints SELECT "candidates".* FROM "candidates"   ORDER BY created_at desc
candidates.where("first_name = ?", "Josh")
puts candidates.to_sql
#prints SELECT "candidates".* FROM "candidates"   ORDER BY created_at desc
```

I'm using rails and activerecord (4.1.1)

Comment: By the way, since you are using Rails 4, you can use a cleaner syntax: `Candidate.order(created_at: :desc)` and `candidates.where(first_name: "Josh")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's working as you'd expect, but the result is a new scope rather than adjusting the existing one.  i.e. try it something like this:

```
candidates = Candidate.order("created_at desc")
puts candidates.to_sql
#prints SELECT "candidates".* FROM "candidates"   ORDER BY created_at desc
candidates = candidates.limit(20)
puts candidates.to_sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining them:

`candidates = Candidate.where("first_name = ?", "Josh").limit(20).order("created_at desc")`

Comment: i cant chain them, as im tyring to dynamically create the query